# How in Excel calculate the sum of all values from a table column matching conditions - like in SQL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How in Excel calculate the sum of all values from a table column matching conditions - for example, the values in one column must equal the value given?

The following example shows well what I mean:

[image: Example]

Using SQL to do something like this would be easy

```
SELECT sum(fee) FROM excel WHERE year='2022' AND month='February';
```

But what is the best way to do something like this in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SUMIFS()` function. Try-

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C7,A2:A7,2022,B2:B7,"February")
```

Also can utilize `FILTER()` like-

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C7,(A2:A7=2022)*(B2:B7="February")))
```

[image]